# How to pass a Lambda Expression as method parameter with EF

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, lambda, linq-expressions

How do I pass an EF expression as a method parameter?

To illustrate my question I have created a pseudo code example:

The first example is my method today. The example utilizes EF and a Fancy Retry Logic.
What I need to do is to encapsulate the Fancy Retry Logic so that it becomes more generic and does not duplicate.

In the second example is how I want it to be, with a helper method that accepts the EF expression as a parameter.

This would be a trivial thing to do with SQL, but I want to do it with EF so that I can benefit from the strongly typed objects.

First Example:

```
public static User GetUser(String userEmail)
{
    using (MyEntities dataModel = new MyEntities ())
    {
        var query =  FancyRetryLogic(() =>
        {
            (dataModel.Users.FirstOrDefault<User>(x => x.UserEmail == userEmail)));
        });

        return query;
    }
}
```

Second Example:

```
T RetryHelper<T>(Expression<Func<T, TValue>> expression)
{
    using (MyEntities dataModel = new (MyEntities ())
    {

        var query = FancyRetryLogic(() =>
                    {
                        return dataModel.expression
                    });
    }
}

public User GetUser(String userEmail)
{
    return RetryHelper<User>(<User>.FirstOrDefault<User>(x => x.UserEmail == userEmail))
}
```

Comment: could you reformat this a bit, hard to follow - others would read / help with it more

Comment: The SO editor is so hard to work with, but maybe you have a specific question that I can answer?

Comment: did you try casting your query to `.AsQueryable()`? that way you can 'move' it around, filter later etc. - I think that's what you're after here.

Comment: for the editor - just in VS before copying, take 'full lines' (copy lines don't text) and it needs roughly 'one tab', that usually works perfect.

Comment: I will try the .AsQueryable()  Thanks!

Comment: just did post some more on this, best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
public TValue RetryHelper<T, TValue>(Func<ObjectSet<T>, TValue> func)
    where T : class
{
    using (MyEntities dataModel = new MyEntities())
    {
        var entitySet = dataModel.CreateObjectSet<T>();
        return FancyRetryLogic(() =>
               {
                   return func(entitySet);
               });
    }
}

public User GetUser(String userEmail)
{
    return RetryHelper<User, User>(u => u.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserEmail == userEmail));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!
This is exactly what I need and it worked straight out of the box, without the need to change your code in any way!

Answer (score 1):

Just to post what we discussed already...

Here is a link that might help you, I think it has something similar to what you need.

[Using AsQueryable With Linq To Objects And Linq To SQL](http://weblogs.asp.net/zeeshanhirani/archive/2008/07/31/using-asqueryable-with-linq-to-objects-and-linq-to-sql.aspx)

[How do I cache an IQueryable object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008404/how-do-i-cache-an-iqueryable-object)

I've seen better examples but I don't have them handy, basically as I mentioned you can use that to keep your query in a form so that you can further filter, change until the very last moment when you know all is done and can actually realize and enumerate the query.

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks! I have decided to use the other solution that worked perfectly!